# Java Lists list item values

Tags: java, list, guava, apache-commons

I have a List for example and I want to call a function on them and list returned answers

```
final List<String> sources = new ArrayList<>();
// initialize
final List<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
for(final String source : sources)
    answers.add(calculate(source));
```

Is there any standard function in `GoogleGuava` or `ApacheCommons` to use it instead of these messy codes

Like (example purpose):

```
final List<String> answers = Lists.calculate(sources, new CalculateListener(..));
```

And for easy understanding: `UnderscoreJs` in JavaScript has a method `map` I want something like that in java `GoogleGuava` or `ApacheCommons` if exists

Answer (score 3):

You can play a bit with the [`Function`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) interface and the [`Iterables`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) class.

From what I can see from your example, you're trying to **transform** a *source* to *calculated source*, so the code would look like:

```
Function<String, String> transformer = new Function<String, String>() {
    public String apply(String source) {
        return calculate(source);
    }
};
Iterable<String> calculatedSources = Iterables.transform(sources, transformer);
List<String> calculatedSourcesAsAList = Lists.newArrayList(calculatedSources);
```

---

As a side note, this often seen type of operation is very well covered in the Java8's Stream features, where you would have to just *map* the sources to the calculated ones and then collect the result. And it's just a one-liner:

```
sources.stream().map(source -> calculate(source)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: it's exactly what I want

Comment: Nice. Well...Guava has these features, but if you update to Java8, you won't need Guava (for this kind of operation). :)

Comment: I need it for android, android doesn't support Java8 I think

Comment: It doesn't, yes. Probably in the future it will.

Comment: Just wondering why you didn't suggest `Lists.transform` instead of `Iterables.transform`? The main reason I can see is that you would not want `calculatedSources` to be a view onto the underlying list.